# General configuration issue when using Dalek with Grunt

Tags: javascript, testing, gruntjs, gui-testing, dalekjs

i have a splitted my gruntfile by using the load-grunt-config functionality as described in `http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/tooling/supercharging-your-gruntfile/?redirect_from_locale=de`. I also created a module for dalek as described in

```
https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-dalek
```

it looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  dalek: {
    options: {
      browser: ['phantomjs'],
      reporter: ['html', 'junit', 'json'],
    },

    dist: {
      src: ['tests/gui/dalekjs/dakektest.js']
    }
  }
};
```

When executing `grunt -v` in the console i see following output in the console:

It says no files, but when i use:

```
module.exports = {
  dalek: {
    options: {
      browser: ['phantomjs'],
      reporter: ['html', 'junit', 'json'],
    },

    files: {
      src: ['tests/gui/dalekjs/dakektest.js']
    }
  }
};
```

everything works fine!

Any ideas why?

Cheers izocan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in a google groups discussion here: [General issue when using Dalek with Grunt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dalekjs/P8l098iVpPM)